# Linebreak of URL in bib in own bibstyle

Tags: biblatex, urls

I have to use my own bibstyle for my thesis, but I have some trouble with longer URLs, which do not break correctly at the end of a line.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
        citestyle=authoryear-comp,
        bibstyle=ownstyle,
        firstinits=true,
        terseinits=true,
        dashed=false,
        backend=biber,
        isbn=false,
        url=true,
        maxnames=2,
        maxbibnames=99
    ]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}

Plain text \cite{Name}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is my lit.bib file

```
@misc{Name,
 author = {Author},
 editor = {Editor},
 title = {{title}},
 url = {http://www.asd.org/text-text-text/texttexttexttext-texttexttext-texttexttext-text-text-texttexttext-texttexttext},
 urldate = {2015-01-08},
 urltime = {17:21}
}
```

And this my own bibstyle

```
\ProvidesFile{heidelberg.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{urltime}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{urlday}
    {}
    {\stripzeros{\thefield{urlday}}\adddot}%
  \iffieldundef{urlmonth}
    {}
    {\stripzeros{\thefield{urlmonth}}\adddot}%
  \printfield{urlyear}%
}

\renewbibmacro{url+urldate}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{}{%
        \printtext{\newline[Online im Internet:]}%
        \addspace%
        \printtext{URL:}%
        \addspace%
        \printfield{url}
        \printtext[brackets]{%
            \printtext{Stand:}%
            \addspace%
            \printurldate\addcomma\addspace
            \printfield{urltime}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

This is how it looks like atm:
[image]

It goes over the edge.

Another URL looks like this:

[image]

The URL should start right next to the "URL:" and has a line break before an "/" or "-".

I tried various examples but non worked for me so far.

Comment: `-` is generally not a valid break point for URLs. You will have to add `-` as a break point for `\url`. I think it is an option to the package, see the manual for the `url` package

Comment: Yes, but how...?

Comment: Run this command: `texdoc url`

Comment: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7008/zeilenumbruche-in-bibliografielinks

Answer (score 2):

To get better hyphenated urls you can load package `url` with the line:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

In your given code are several errors. I corrected them in the following MWE. Please the the comments in the code. `< =======` marks the main changings.

If you use an own style it is important to use one name for it.  I used file `ownstyle.bbx` and therefore I (and you too) have to use the style name `ownstyle`.  In your there was a for your wrong `heidelberg.bbx`,  I guess the file you copied parts of the code?

Package `filecontents` is only used for my MWE to have **all** needed files together in **one compilable** MWE.

Package `showframe` is used to visualize the resulting typing area.  To have citings and bibliography on one resulting page I used `scrartcl` instead of your `scrreprt` ...

So with the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} % <=======================================
% < ===== creates bib file
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Name,
  author = {Author},
  editor = {Editor},
  title  = {{title}},
  url    = {http://www.asd.org/text-text-text/texttexttexttext-texttexttext-texttexttext-text-text-texttexttext-texttexttext},
  urldate = {2015-01-08},
  urltime = {17:21}
}
\end{filecontents*}

% < ===== creates ownstyle.bbx
\begin{filecontents*}{ownstyle.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{ownstyle.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{urltime}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{urlday}
    {}
    {\stripzeros{\thefield{urlday}}\adddot}%
  \iffieldundef{urlmonth}
    {}
    {\stripzeros{\thefield{urlmonth}}\adddot}%
  \printfield{urlyear}%
}

\renewbibmacro{url+urldate}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{}{%
        \printtext{\newline[Online im Internet:]}%
        \addspace%
        \printtext{URL:}%
        \addspace%
        \printfield{url}
        \printtext[brackets]{%
            \printtext{Stand:}%
            \addspace%
            \printurldate\addcomma\addspace
            \printfield{urltime}%
        }%
    }%
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <=============================== better urls
\usepackage{csquotes} % < ============================= to avoid warning
\usepackage[%
  citestyle=authoryear,%-comp
  bibstyle=ownstyle, % <================================================
  backend=biber,
  isbn=false,
  url=true,
  maxnames=2,
  maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <=======================================


\begin{document}
Plain text \cite{Name}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I got the result you wanted:

[image]